# Spring buisness logic validation code duplication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, jpa

I'm thinking about best solution for handling of buisness logic validation in service layer.
I've service class where I few methods that should be validated for same buisness logic validation, if I do raw validation with if statement then Intellij shows that there is code duplication.

First approach

```
@Override
    public ReportDTO createCommentReport(Long id, ReportReasonDTO reasonDTO, String username) {
        log.info("Creating a report for comment with id {}", id);
        User userReporting = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        Comment commentFound = findCommentById(id);
        if (commentFound.getTopic().isClosed()) {
            log.error(EXCEPTION_OCCURRED, new TopicIsClosedException(TOPIC_WHERE_COMMENT_IS_CLOSED_EXCEPTION));
            throw new TopicIsClosedException(TOPIC_WHERE_COMMENT_IS_CLOSED_EXCEPTION);
        }
        String reason = reasonDTO.reason();
        Report reportBuilt = ReportMapper.buildReport(userReporting, reason, commentFound);
        reportRepository.save(reportBuilt);
        log.info("Report created");
        return ReportMapper.buildReportTopicDTO(reportBuilt);
    }
```

Approach where I separate method of validation topic entity,

```
@Override
    public ReportDTO createCommentReport(Long id, ReportReasonDTO reasonDTO, String username) {
        log.info("Creating a report for comment with id {}", id);
        User userReporting = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        Comment commentFound = findCommentById(id);
        topicValidator.validateTopicClosed(commentFound.getTopic());
        String reason = reasonDTO.reason();
        Report reportBuilt = ReportMapper.buildReport(userReporting, reason, commentFound);
        reportRepository.save(reportBuilt);
        log.info("Report created");
        return ReportMapper.buildReportTopicDTO(reportBuilt);
    }
```

Options I'm considering:

- Duplicating code in service methods
- Creating separate class for validation
- Creating method in service class (but I think it gonna break SRP)

Comment: Consider creating a utility class and writing method there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, creating a utility class and move the duplicated code would be the best approach.

You can create a class with `static` method and reuse the logic.

Also, I've seen people creating `UtilityService` and injecting it.

Though, it isn't much of a difference. I would suggest you pick up one and follow it as a convention throughout the project.